# How do I programmatically logout & redirect using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to do something like:

```
flash[:alert] = "You've been logged out. Thanks for using us!"
redirect_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

in my controller, but it isn't working. What's the right approach to programmatically log someone out?

Thanks!
Chris.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L241) will likely help you out.

Comment: Awesome thanks, just what I needed!

Comment: write an answer then =) it's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

As per @d-side answered, it's as simple as:

```
  def logout
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes
    redirect_to '/'
  end
```